# Exception thrown using VS publish on 1 developers machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

When deploying 1 application through Visual Studio 2017 & 2015 one of our devs is getting the exception below raised in the servers event logs.

No other developer gets this exception, and it seems to happen for all apps that developer tries to deploy.

Here's what the log says about it on the server ...

```
The description for Event ID 1 from source Web Deploy cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

User: S0000878\WROW
Client IP: 10.100.177.100:80
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1972.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: 94589097-54ba-4753-a37b-32571bfe6b8f
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-GB
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-GB
ServerVersion: 9.0.1962.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: auto, Path: 
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID '94589097-54ba-4753-a37b-32571bfe6b8f'. Request Timestamp: '16/05/2017 10:26:59'. Error Details:
System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt16()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageDeserializer.GetNextEntryType()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SerializationProvider..ctor(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, PackageDeserializer deserializer)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageDeserializer.GetSerializationProvider()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
```

I'm at a loss because the deployment process works from all other dev machines and from our build boxes, and yet it's only the server that complains.

What should I be looking for on the developers machine that might help indicate the real problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by proxy settings on the developers machine.

this sort of problem can be caused by tools like Fiddler (often used by developers to debug API calls to web services).

The developer seems to have fixed it by repairing VS in this instance suggesting that there was also an issue with the VS install.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was caused by a security software in our environment. However, while doing research about this issue, I noticed that these are also required for Web Deploy to work:

- Management Services should be installed (Add Role and Features > Web
  Server)
- Web Management Service sand Web Deploy Agent Service hould be
  running
- Make sure Fiddler or any other similar software is not
  running while publishing
- Make sure TCP port 8172 is open in the
  server

Source: [Web Deploy experienced a connection problem (ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED)](https://port135.com/2020/08/01/web-deploy-experienced-problem-error-connection-terminated/)

Comment: It was fiddler for me... forgot it was even running! Thank you!